# How can I optimize this Python program to find palindromes?

Tags: python, optimization, palindrome

I made this Python program that generates multi-word palindromes from a given list of words.(A palindrome being a sequence of characters that reads the same forwards and backwards, disregarding spaces, punctuation, and capitalization.) The program takes a list of words and forms combinations of a specified range of lengths (between the minimum and maximum number of words per combination). For each combination, it checks if the combination is valid (valid meaning it is a palindrome and contains at least two distinct words) and then joins the words together to form a single text. The program cleans the combined text by removing non-alphanumeric characters and converting it to lowercase. If the cleaned text is a palindrome, the combination of words is stored in a list of found palindromes. Finally, the program prints all the discovered palindromes, maintaining the original word formatting with spaces between the words. The problem is that the algorithm is super slow. Even with only 15 words, minimum palindrome length 3, and maximum palindrome length 7, it takes over four minutes. How can I optimize this code so that it doesn't take as long?

```
import itertools

def main():
    word_list = ['a', 'man', 'plan', 'canal', 'panama', 'the', 'of', 'and', 'to', 'in', 'is', 'you', 'that', 'it', 'he']
    min_words, max_words = 3, 7

    found_palindromes = []

    for n in range(min_words, max_words + 1):
        for combination in itertools.product(word_list, repeat=n):
            if len(set(combination)) > 1:
                combined_text = ''.join(combination)
                cleaned_text = ''.join(char for char in combined_text if char.isalnum()).lower()

                if cleaned_text == cleaned_text[::-1]:
                    found_palindromes.append(' '.join(combination))

    for palindrome in found_palindromes:
        print(palindrome)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried simplifying the code a bit, removing unneeded functions, improving the logic, but it didn't help that much (only about a 1% decrease in time). I'm not that good at coding so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: A 1% improvement sounds about right for the kind of things you're trying. To do better you have to find a way to do *less work*. For example, not every word combination can go at the beginning and end of your palindrome; you can't use "of" and "to" together because that combination is already not a palindrome.  In fact of all the words in your list I can only find four combinations that work together for the beginning and end. How many palindromes did your slow algorithm find?

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion with a bit of short circuiting based on incompatible starting/ending words:

```
def findPal(words, minLen=3, maxLen=7, start="", end=""):

    result = set() # avoid duplicate patterns in result

    if start[:len(end)] != end[::-1][:len(start)]:
        return result # mismatched on common start and end
    
    if len(start)>len(end):
        part = start[len(end):][::-1]
        if not any(w.endswith(part) for w in words):
            return result # no compatible endings
    if len(end)>len(start):
        part = end[::-1][len(start):]
        if not any(w.startswith(part) for w in words):
            return result # no compatible starts
        
    for word in words:
        if minLen <= 1:
            combined = start+word+end
            if combined == combined[::-1] and len(set(combined))>1:
                result.add( (word,) )
        if maxLen == 1: continue
        for left in findPal(words,minLen-1,maxLen-1,start,word+end):
            result.add( (*left,word) )
        for right in findPal(words,minLen-1,maxLen-1,start+word,end):
            result.add( (word,*right) )
            
    return result
```

output:

```
word_list = ['a', 'man', 'plan', 'canal', 'panama', 'the', 'of', 'and',
             'to', 'in', 'is', 'you', 'that', 'it', 'he']

for p in findPal(word_list): # 5 milliseconds
    print(*p)

a man a panama
a man a panama man a panama
a a man a panama a
a man a plan a canal panama
```